# calculate common date ranges with momentjs

Tags: momentjs

I wanted to calculate common date ranges with moment.js for things like:
* yesterday
* week
* week-to-date
* quarter
* quarter-to-date

etc.  I didn't find what I was looking for on Stackoverflow so I thought I would post this for others in case it helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
  // Yesterday
  console.log("yesterday", moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'day').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'day').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("");

  // Week
  console.log("week", moment().startOf('week').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('week').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("week-to-date", moment().startOf('week').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-week", moment().startOf('week').subtract(1, 'week').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('week').subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-week-to-date", moment().startOf('week').subtract(1, 'week').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().subtract(1, 'week').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-year-week", moment().startOf('week').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('week').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-year-week-to-date", moment().startOf('week').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("");

  // Months
  console.log("month", moment().startOf('month').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('month').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("month-to-date", moment().startOf('month').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-month", moment().startOf('month').subtract(1, 'month').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('month').subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-month-to-date", moment().startOf('month').subtract(1, 'month').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-year-month", moment().startOf('month').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('month').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-year-month-to-date", moment().startOf('month').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("");

  // Quarters
  console.log("quarter", moment().startOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("quarter-to-date", moment().startOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-quarter", moment().startOf('quarter').subtract(1, 'quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('quarter').subtract(1, 'quarter').endOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-quarter-to-date", moment().startOf('quarter').subtract(1, 'quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().subtract(1, 'quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-year-quarter", moment().startOf('quarter').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('quarter').subtract(1, 'year').endOf('quarter').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-year-quarter-to-date", moment().startOf('quarter').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("");

  // years
  console.log("year", moment().startOf('year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("year-to-date", moment().startOf('year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-year", moment().startOf('year').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().endOf('year').subtract(1, 'year').endOf('year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("prior-year-to-date", moment().startOf('year').subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'), moment().subtract(1, 'year').format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  console.log("");
```

Comment: You just saved me a ton of work, thank you so much, Jonathan!